# How to run if/else condition for multiple selectbox choices?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to execute a function with if/else conditions, based on a user's selection within a selectbox. The selectbox allows for multiple selections and the options are separated by optgroups.

I've tried the if conditions with .selectedIndex, .option[] selected and now, .indexOf - but nothing seems to follow my intended logic. I'm learning javascript/jQuery, so excuse any newbie faux-pas!

Any suggestions on what I should do?

HTML

```
    <select id="box1" style="width:500px" multiple>
    <optgroup label="Stage I">
    <option selected>Complete</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Stage II">
    <option>Micro two one</option>
    <option>Micro two two</option>
    <option>Intra one</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Stage III">
    <option>Macro two two</option>
    <option>Macro one one</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option>Not applicable</option>
    </select>
<input type="button" onclick="writetext()" value="write">
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

JS

```
function writetext(){
var mytext = $('#text');

var box_1 = $("#box1").val();
if (box_1.indexOf('Complete') > -1){
ctext += "\n- Stage I\n- "+box_1+"\n";}
if ((box_1.indexOf('two one') > -1) || (box_1.indexOf('two two') > -1) || (box_1.indexOf('Intra') > -1)) {
ctext += "\n- Stage II\n- "+box_1.join("\n- ")+"\n";}
if ((box_1.indexOf('Macro two') > -1) || (box_1.indexOf('Macro one') > -1)) {
ctext += "\n- Stage III\n- "+box_14.join("\n- ")+"\n";}

else {ctext += "\n- "+box_1+"\n";}
mytext.value = ctext;        
}
```

**UPDATE**
While the answer below works in this example, it seems like there should be an easier way of interrogating an array derived from multiple selections, within an if statement. If two or more items are selected, is there not a way to ask whether a particular option is selected among multiple selections?

**UPDATE #2** Thanks @andrew for the tip. I think I stumbled onto what I was looking for. It is less elegant that the answer chosen, but does the task at hand using:

```
$.inArray('string to challenge', variable containing object array of selectbox) > -1
```

So, in my example, if I wanted to fire some code if, say 'Intra one' was among the selections, I could do:

```
$.inArray('Intra one', box_1) > -1
```

I'm not sure if one can use a Regex to see if parts of a string are present, but I'm sure there might be a way to do this.

Comment: write is reserved, rename the function. Also box one is a jquery object, .indexOf is an array property (incompatible types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fork of your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmTGU/1/) with some fixes.  You had some syntax errors in the HTML and the javascript.

Change the button HTML like so:

```
<input type="button" value="write" />
```

EDITED...a more reliable way to do it:

```
    $(function() {

    function write() {
        var select = $('#box1');
        var ctext = '';

        select.find('optgroup').each(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            if (el.find('option:selected').length) {
                ctext += "\n- " + el.attr('label') + "\n- ";
                var items = [];
                el.find('option:selected').each(function() {
                    items.push($(this).text());
                });
                ctext += items.join(',') + "\n";
            }
        });

        $('#text').val(ctext);
        return false;
    }

    $('input').click(write);

});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for editing my markup. It looks like even with your code, all the 'if' conditions are skipped and only the 'else' condition is executed. Meaning, the extra text that pertains to each optgroup is not included as would be expected for the conditions. This was exactly the problem I encountered and @andrew comment suggests that .indexOf cannot be used with the box_1 variable?

Comment: Hi.  I modified my example above to provide a more reliable way to do what you want.

Comment: Cool, that certainly did the trick. I have to admit, it is a bit more advanced that I have learned thus far, but I look forward to studying how you used the various methods. In my original example, I tried to execute the function if I could match part of a phrase returned to the 'box_1' object. Can you explain how I could do it with my construct? I guess .indexOf is not the answer - how about .each()?

Comment: Sure.  In your example, box_1 is an array of all the selected values.  When you call indexOf on the array, it returns the index (into the array) of the value (or -1 if not found).  When you call `box_1.join("\n- ")`, that joins all the selected values, not just those for the current optgroup.  You need to obtain each selected value by index (e.g. `box_1[index]`) before using them in the concatenation.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So the first 'if' condition would be `if (box_1.indexOf('Complete') > -1){ctext += "\n- Stage I\n- "+box_1[0]+"\n";}` ? I don't follow how to extend that if, say, two items under optgroup2 were selected - and would then need to be joined?

Comment: To do it that way, first you'd find the index `var completeIndex = box_1.indexOf('Complete');`. Then you'd do the `if (completeIndex > -1)`. Then you'd get the value at that index `box_1[completeIndex]`.  That all works OK. But then in the second if, you have 3 indexes to find. Then you need to know which one to add to the "Stage II" text.  The code gets very lengthy. A better algorithm is: Loop each optgroup, check if any children option elements are selected. If so, print out the optgroup label and loop the selected children options, outputting their values. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think i figured out what I was asking you earlier, see update #2. I used .inArray to interrogate whether my option of interest was included within the array of selections. I can build if/else arguments based on that, i think.